# class not found exception in eclipse Groovy program

Tags: groovy

This is my simple Groovy program, i have added the groovy plugins in the eclipse.I am using the Eclipse mars(2018-12) And when i try to run the program, it is showing the ClassNotFoundException. Also it showing the "internal error occurred 'Refresh DSLD scripts'". But the java programs are working well in it.

This is simple Groovy program:-

```
class NewOne{
static void main(String[] args){
println("hello world");
}
}
```

This is my result:-

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: groovy.ui.Console
at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.Rootloader.findclass(RootLoader.findClass
(RootLoader.java:179)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader.loadClass(RootLoader.java:151)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
at 
org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter.rootLoader(GroovyStarter.java:104)
at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter.main(GroovyStarter.java:136)
```

Comment: Does https://github.com/groovy/groovy-eclipse/issues/587 help?

Comment: If you have Groovy 2.5 or higher and you chose Run As > Groovy Console, you will get this error. You can run as Java Application since you have a class with a main method. Or you can add the libraries necessary for Groovy Console. I can dig up a link to help if you want the console ui to work.

Comment: You can also switch to Groovy 2.4 compiler which provides groovy-all and the Groovy Console will start without issue.

Comment: Thank you. But when we switch to Groovy 2.4 compiler, it is showing some warnings in the Eclipse console. Does it cause any problems in the future?

Comment: If you need Groovy 2.5 then you should use that. If you want to run console under 2.5 you would need to add its dependencies to your project. 2.4 provided them inside groovy-all. 2.5 got rid of the fat all jar.